# Double Linked List Middle Insert doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

```
import math
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, next = None, prev = None):
        self.data = val
        self.next = next
        self.prev = prev

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.count = 0

    def StartInsert(self, val):
        newNode = Node(val)
        if self.count == 0:
            self.head = newNode
            self.tail = newNode
        else:
            self.head.prev = newNode
            newNode.next = self.head
            self.head = newNode
        self.count += 1

    def EndInsert(self, val):
        newNode = Node(val)
        if self.count == 0:
            self.head = newNode
            self.tail = newNode
        else:
            self.tail.next = newNode
            newNode.prev = self.tail
            self.tail = newNode
        self.count += 1

    def MiddleInsert(self, val):
        newNode = Node(val)
        if self.count == 0:
            self.head = newNode
            self.tail = newNode
        else:
            index = math.ceil(self.count/2)-1
            temp = self.head
            while index > 0:
                temp = temp.next
                index -= 1
            temp.next = Node(val, temp.next)
            temp.prev = Node(temp.prev.data, temp)
        self.count +=1


    def delete(self, val):
        curNode = self.head
        while curNode != None:
            if curNode.data == val:
                if curNode.prev != None:
                    curNode.prev.next = curNode.next
                else:
                    self.head = curNode.next

                if curNode.next != None:
                    curNode.next.prev = curNode.prev
                else:
                    self.tail = curNode.prev

                self.count -= 1

            curNode = curNode.next

    def reverse(self):
        temp = None
        current = self.head
        while current != None:
            temp = current.prev
            current.prev = current.next
            current.next = temp
            current = current.prev
        if temp:
            self.head = temp.prev
            self.tail = temp.next



    def traverse(self):
        s = ""
        p = self.head
        while p is not None:
            s += str(p.data) + ' ';
            p = p.next
        print(s + "| count: " + str(self.count))

list = LinkedList()
list.EndInsert("a")
list.StartInsert("b")
list.StartInsert("c")
list.EndInsert("d")
list.MiddleInsert("c")
list.traverse()

list.reverse()
list.traverse()
```

Middle Insert gives correct return but doesn't stop. I did the same method for singly linked list but it doesn't seem to work properly for double linked list. It returns proper value but keep getting stuck at the while loop.

I am trying to figure how to connect the newNode(). Please help me by showing code and the reason I get such error.

Thank you so much for helping.

Answer (score 1):

In a doubly linked list, you must maintain prev and next *pointers*. In `MiddleInsert`, once you have selected the element that you want to add the new node after, you must insert the new element between that one and its follower.

Let us call `C` the new node, `A` the selected node and say `B=A.next`. Before insertion, you have `A.next == B` and `B.prev == A` ; after insertion, you want to have
`A.next == C`, `C.prev == A`, `C.next == B` and `B.prev == C`.

Just write that in `MiddleInsert` (unrelated, but no need for the `math` module here, and `for ... in range(...)` is the Pythonic way for counting loops):

```
def MiddleInsert(self, val):
    newNode = Node(val)
    if self.count == 0:
        self.head = newNode
        self.tail = newNode
    elif self.count == 1:
        self.tail = newNode
        self.head.next = newNode
        newNode.prev = self.head
    else:
        index = (self.count-1) // 2
        temp = self.head
        for i in range(index):
            temp = temp.next
        temp.next.prev = newNode
        newNode.next = temp.next
        newNode.prev = temp
        temp.next = newNode
    self.count +=1
```

Comment: I am not sure that the middle being the last element is correctly handled in this case: temp.next.prev will raise an error

Comment: @LouisCaron: You are right. I forgot the corner case when the list contains only one element. In any other case the middle element cannot be the last one.

Answer (score 1):

An initial error is that you are creating more `Node` that necessarily in your `MiddleInsert` method.

This can lead you to finding the error in your code.

After removing these extra creations, you should simply switch the prev and next pointers, checking that the `temp` is not actually the last element:

```
def MiddleInsert(self, val):
    newNode = Node(val)
    if self.count == 0:
        self.head = newNode
        self.tail = newNode
    else:
        index = math.ceil(self.count/2)-1
        temp = self.head
        while index > 0:
            temp = temp.next
            index -= 1
        newNode.next = temp.next
        temp.next = newNode
        newNode.prev = temp
        if newNode.next is not None:
            newNode.next.prev = newNode
    self.count +=1
```

Comment: I have kept your formatting for the code with as little changes as possible, but the answer by Serge Ballesta as good points for code refactoring (if the issue with last element is fixed)